# Not detecting columns

Tags: python, tabular, tabula, tabula-py

I was parsing bank statement using tabula-py in which columns are seperated by vertical margins but row are not separated.
so i use **stream mode** but if in any page there is not entry for any column then tabula merges them as one
for code

```
tables=tabula.read_pdf("pdfname.pdf",pages='all')
```

So i use **columns option** to manually select columns

```
tables=tabula.read_pdf("pdfname.pdf",pages='all',columns= ['27.0,68.0,272.0,357.5,397.0,474.5,553.0,631.0'])
```

but it does nothing like tabula is not even reading the options
output is same as previous
Sorry i can not post the table for privacy purposes.

[my tables is somewhat like it
you can check image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/f40V0.png]

Answer (score 0):

The `columns` keyword argument should be an array of numbers:

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf("pdfname.pdf",
                         pages='all',
                         columns=[27.0,68.0,272.0,357.5,397.0,474.5,553.0,631.0])
```

Comment: Does it work with the Tabula application? You can get it at https://tabula.technology

Comment: No, Tabula application also merging the columns.

Comment: Have been having having this problem, am sorry to say that whether `columns` is a list (square brackets) or a tuple (round brackets) makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `tabula-py` is just a wrapper of `tabula-java`, so the extraction accuracy is the same as tabula app. Try [PDFplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) instead.